# How to run plain old JUnit tests in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, junit

I want to test some regular classes and methods that have nothing to do with Android, with JUnit in Android Studio 1.1.0

In the test package I have the following class:

```
public class ParametrizedStaticMapsRequestTest extends TestCase {


    @SmallTest
    public void testBuildingStaticMapsRequestURL() {
        System.out.println("asd");
    }


}
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

I read on the internet that this happens because Im trying to run it as an Android Test. I want to run it as a plain old JUnit test, like I was able to do in Eclipse. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using an official but experimental functionality: [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support)

Comment: I did everything the way they've explained it but then my test project (or module, dont know the difference) disappeared. Then I added some packages and placed the test inside them and ran the tests, but got the same error. How are the test packages supposed to be called and structured and where should I place them?

Comment: oops, closed AS, opened and was able to run the tests. Cheers